# Would like to create a report which displays the 3 most recent entries for a category

Tags: ms-access

I have created a workout database.  I would like to create a report which displays my workout history by Cardio or Strength (done), grouping by Exercise_Name (done) and then listing only the 3 most recent results for that particular Exercise_Name. I can get it to display all results, or I can limit it to the last 30 days or other time parameter, but there are cases where I may not have done that particular exercise for an extended period and I would like to see my most recent activity.

I have a table tblExercise_Activity with the following fields
Trainee (Lookup from tblEntity)
Exercise_Date (Date field)
Exercise_Name (Lookup from tblExercises.  This table also identifies if it was cardio or strength)
Exercise_Sets (num)
Exercise_Reps (num)
Weight
Duration_Minutes (h:mm:ss)
Cardio_Intensity (Lookup list)
Notes
Trainer (Lookup from tblEntity)
Exercise_Activity_ID (Autonumber)

I have looked at Crosstab Queries but that does not appear to be the right track.  I have attempted to modify my query to Top 3 but I am limited on the sorting that can be done and the results that can be displayed.

I would apprecieate any constructive guidance.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: If you've tried Top 3, you need to use ORDER BY <your timestamp> DESC.  Which should give the latest 3.

Comment: If you want TOP 3 for a specific exercise then apply filter criteria as well. If you want TOP 3 for all exercies, that will require a subquery. Common topic.